# UNAUTHORIZED with API key

Tags: servicestack

I try to authenticate a call from a service to another service using an API key. An administrative service creates 'service account users' when it is started for the first time. Now when a service calls another service I have:

```
Client = new JsonServiceClient("http://TheOtherServer:1234")
{
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(<the string with my api key>, ""),
};
//.....
var request = new RequestDtoOfOtherServer
{
     //set some request props
};
try
{
    var result = Client.Get(request);
    //do something with result
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     Log.Error($"Error: {ex}");
     throw;
}
```

Whatever key I use from the 2 keys issued for the calling service user, I always get a 401 UNAUTHORIZED error. I turned on the `RequestLogsFeature` on the receiving service but there is NO entry.

The method I call is annotated with `[RequiresAnyRole("User", "Administrator", "bizbusops-service", "SYSTEM")]` and the user which is related to the API key I use is in the Role `bizbusops-service`. Also when I use my WPF UI and login with that user (with username / password) I can access this method without error. So there must be something wrong with establishing the server-to-server connection and / or the API key.

What am I missing?

- Does the above code with NetworkCredential establish a session between the two servers and issue a cookie?
- I see in the Redis DB that two keys are issued to the user account of the service. Can I use both of them or do I have to set the **Environment** and **KeyType** somewhere on the server side, e.g. in a RequestFilter?

**UDATE**
On the server which **receives** the authentication calls I have configured the `AuthFeature` Plugin like so:

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(), 
    new IAuthProvider[] {
        new BizBusAuthProvider(),
        new ApiKeyAuthProvider(AppSettings)
        {
            KeyTypes = new []{"secret", "publishable"},
        },
    }
));
```

This configuration generated 4 API keys for every new user, the ones defined above and the two created by default.

Comment: what does your AuthFeature configuration look like?

Comment: try moving ApiKeyAuthProvider so it's the first AuthProvider listed or change to [use BearerToken instead of Credentials](http://docs.servicestack.net/api-key-authprovider#interoperable).

Comment: Yeah moving it at the first place worked with Credentials! Why is that? I first got a forbidden error because the default seems to be `RequireSecureConnection = true`. Is this dependent on the environment or valid in general? It means SSL right? (Which I do not have in dev environment).

Comment: Because .NET's WebRequest only sends Credentials when they get a 401 challenge response and ServiceStack's 401 WWW-Authenticate response instructs the client to try authenticating using the first auth provider. Yeah `RequireSecureConnection=true` is the default which requires that the connection should be secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to use `Credentials` to send the API Key then you'll need to register the `ApiKeyAuthProvider` so it's the first AuthProvider listed, e.g:

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(), 
    new IAuthProvider[] {
        new ApiKeyAuthProvider(AppSettings)
        {
            KeyTypes = new []{"secret", "publishable"},
        },
        new BizBusAuthProvider(),
    }
));
```

This is so when .NET's WebRequest receives a 401 WWW-Authenticate challenge response it will automatically add the `Credentials` when retrying the Request.

Otherwise you can use a BearerToken to send the API Key, e.g:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient(baseUrl) {
    BearerToken = apiKey
};
```